# How to import module from a sibling directory in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7

```
DATAMINING/  
        DISEASED/  
                kmeans.py
       NORMAL/
                kmeans.py
```

I am a beginner in python 2.7.My directory structure is given above.
I want to import DISEASED/kmeans.py to NORMAL/kmeans.py.
How to do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "import sys
sys.path.append('..\DISEASED')
from kmeans import cluster_item"      But it is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import `DISEASED/kmeans.py` module like this,

```
from DISEASED import kmeans
```

**Note**: You must run `NORMAL/kmeans.py` file from `DATAMINING` directory like this,

```
python -m NORMAL.kmeans
```

Comment: add `__init__.py` file in NORMAL and DISEASED directory.

Comment: Will it be an empty .py file or I have to write something in __init__.py??